# Django, href and string

Tags: python, django

Abit new to Django, and this is probably a silly question.

javascript variable:

```
<script>
    bar = 'foo'
</script>
```

if I have a href like this:

```
<a style="color:black;" href="{% url 'manager:file' %}">Click</a>
```

which directs to

```
url(r'^getfile/$', views.dd, name='file'),
```

and

```
def dd(request, str):
    print(str) <---- print 'foo'
```

How can I with the href, get the string in the variable bar to the view function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add value of bar to the end of the url in client side as a query string:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {  // Dirty hack :-/
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.replace($(this).attr('href') + '?bar=' + bar);
});
```

and get it in server side using this code:

```
def dd(request):
    str = request.GET.get('bar', '')
    print(str) <---- print 'foo'
```

Comment: is there any limit to how long the url can be? I were going to send a json(string), which may get long

Comment: Yes there is. In this case it's better to make an ajax POST request

Comment: The whole URL should not be longer than 2083 characters